# AttributeError: object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, mysql-python

I trying to Add data from a json API into a MySql Database with python but i get the Error:
xx=validate_string(i.get(x, None))AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

My Code:

```
import requests
import json
import pymysql

headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'api-key': 'xxxxx'
}

r = requests.get('https://api.example.com', params={
  'Id': '432',
  'Id2': '6'
}, headers = headers)
package_json=r.json()

con = pymysql.connect(host='domain.net', user='user', passwd='pass', db='test')
cursor = con.cursor()

def validate_string(val):
    if val != None:
        if type(val) is int:
            return str(val).encode('utf-8')
        else:
            return val


for i in package_json:
    # start off your query string
    query = 'Insert into xxxx ('
    t1=[]
    first_item = True
    for x in i:
        xx=validate_string(i.get(x, None))
        # append the value to the value list
        t1.append(xx)
        if not first_item:
            # add a comma and space to the query if it's not the first item
            query += ', '
        # add the field name to the query
        query += x
        # mark that it's no longer the first item
        first_item = False

    # finish off the query string
    query += ') VALUES {}'
    # and send the query
    cursor.execute(query.format(tuple(t1)))

con.commit()
con.close()
```

Any ideas to fix?

Comment: `for i in package_json` gives you a list of keys of `package_json`. Did you want to maybe use `for key, i in package_json.items()`? or `for i in package_json.values()`?

Comment: i just want to grab the things from the API and put them into a Mysql Database

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that when you iterate a dictionary, you doin't get the "items" it it, you get the keys. If you are given:

```py
for x in {"a": 1, "b": 2}:
    print(x)
```

You will get:

```
a
b
```

or more explicitly `list({"a": 1, "b": 2}) == ['a', 'b']`

So in your code, `for i in package_json` is not giving you back what you expect. It is giving you the sting keys (`i`) from the dictionary `package_json`. Since `i` is a string, it has no `get()` method and you code throws the error:

```
xx = validate_string(i.get(x, None))
>>> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Note: you have the same issue here as in the line prior you do:

```py
for x in i:
```

At this point `x` is a single character from the string `i`.

Without know what your `package_json` typically looks like, it is impossible to  say for sure how you should structure your code. If you update your post with and example we might be able to help more. Maye start by doing:

```py
for key, i in package_json.items():
```

and see if that helps.

again to help more we need to see an example of your `package_json` .

**Addendum:**

Given your `package_json` with corrections looks a bit like:

```py
package_json = {
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Example",
            "links": {"websiteUrl": "https://example.com",},
            "summary": "This is a summary",
            "status": 1,
            "classId": 0,
            "screenshots": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "title": "This is a screenshot",
                    "description": "a screenshot",
                    "thumbnailUrl": "https://example.com",
                    "url": "https://example.com"
                }
            ],
            "mainFileId": 0,
            "latestFiles": [
                {
                    "id": 0,
                    "isAvailable": True,
                    "displayName": "example file",
                    "fileName": "example",
                    "releaseType": 1,
                    "fileStatus": 1,
                    "hashes": [
                        {
                            "value": "string",
                            "algo": 1
                        }
                    ],
                    "fileDate": "2019-08-24T14:15:22Z",
                    "fileLength": 0,
                    "downloadUrl": "https://example.com",
                    "Versions": [
                        "string"
                    ],
                    "latestFilesIndexes": [
                        {
                            "Version": "1",
                            "fileId": 0,
                            "filename": "example file",
                            "releaseType": 1,
                            "VersionTypeId": 0,
                            "Loader": 0
                        }
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
}
```

Then you can likely build an insert statement like:

```py
SQL_STATEMENT = """
    INSERT INTO xxxx (
        name,
        website,
        summary,
        screenshot,
        file,
        filename,
        version
    ) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s);
"""

for data_item in package_json["data"]:
    name = data_item["name"]
    website = data_item["links"]["websiteUrl"]
    summary = data_item["summary"]
    screenshot = data_item["screenshots"][0]["thumbnailUrl"]
    file = data_item["latestFiles"][0]["downloadUrl"]
    filename = data_item["latestFiles"][0]["fileName"]
    version = data_item["latestFiles"][0]["latestFilesIndexes"][0]["Version"]
    cursor.execute (SQL_STATEMENT, (name, website, summary, screenshot, file, filename, version))
```

Comment: My answer from the API will look like this:

https://pastebin.com/976JYS9E (cant write it here because too long)

and i want to add things like Name, Website, summary, screenshot, file, filename, version  in my database

Comment: some of those data points are lists. How would those items be added to your sql database? Do you want to add just the first item int he list if the data point is a list?

Comment: No eg.: i want to add in the item"screenshot" so i just want to add the link to the thumbnailurl into my database

Comment: "screenshots" is a list like many other elements. If there are two screenshots and two latest files how many rows are you adding? 1, 2, 4?

Comment: oh sorry then yes only 1 row